# Can I set different 'template_name's inside of django TemplateView?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-rest-framework

Using Django views I want to redirect a user based on their permission levels.

I have a template view that works.

```
class theTableView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'adminTable.html'
```

What I am trying to do looks something like this:

```
class TheTableView(generic.TemplateView):
    if self.request.user.is_superuser==True:
        tempTemplate = 'goodAdminTable.html'
    elseif self.request.user.is_authenticated==True:
        tempTemplate = 'goodUserTable.html'
    template_name = tempTemplate
```

I was able to do this in the rest_framework api return for the data.

I need to be able to check the user permissions and redirect them to the appropriate template_name based on the results.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by overriding get_template_names() method like this

```
class theTableView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'adminTable.html'

    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            template_name = 'goodAdminTable.html'
        elif self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            template_name = 'goodUserTable'
        else:
            template_name = self.template_name
        return [template_name]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override this method in your TemplateView and just add your logic inside it.

```
 def get_template_names (self):
      return ["your_template.html",]
```